# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class Relativelayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout

i'm new in android.
i just made a layout with 4 textview and 1 relative layout. but when i run its appear a error android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class Relativelayout in logcat. its my code

xml code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.gpsaja.GPSMainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvAddress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<Relativelayout
    android:id="@+id/cantainer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="260dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
    </Relativelayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDegree"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/idDegree"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/idLat" 
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLong"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/idLon" />
</LinearLayout>
```

logcat

```
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792): Process: com.gpsaja, PID: 1792
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gpsaja/com.gpsaja.GPSMainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class Relativelayout
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class Relativelayout
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at com.gpsaja.GPSMainActivity.onCreate(GPSMainActivity.java:43)
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     ... 11 more
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.Relativelayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.gpsaja-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.gpsaja-1, /system/lib]]
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
11-24 01:24:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     ... 21 more
```

help me to fix it.

Comment: Have you changed your gradle dependencies lately?

Comment: **RelativeLayout**

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `RelativeLayout` instead of `Relativelayout`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/cantainer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="260dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

just change your spelling Relativelayout to RelativeLayout. 
Android studio will also help for for writing code in your xml. When you will type just "Rel" it should be show popup you select not need to write complete spelling.

Answer (score 2):

replace Relativelayout with  RelativeLayout

Comment: There's a typo in your answer

Comment: Corrected the typo

Answer (score 1):

Replace the relative layout code with

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/cantainer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="260dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's **RelativeLayout**.
Why are you using empty **RelativeLayout** ? 
If you are using it to create a space then use **View** instead.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `Relativelayout` to `RelativeLayout`, fixed the problem.